# Android Gallery Loading a lot of images from local makes scroll not smooth

Tags: android, bitmap, scroll, gallery, smoothing

I am using the android Gallery widget loading images from Bitmap[] succesfully, but it seemms the scroll is not very smooth. Initial conditions:

- Image resources comes from a local array of Bitmap (previously full filled)
- If i load only three images, it seems going smoother
- The size of each individual item is light weighted Bitmap (less than 30KB)
- The dimensions of each individual item is like 200x350 px

What could i do to optimize it ?

Thx in advance!!

Comment: Are you using any asynchronous image loading library? Have you followed view holder pattern?

Comment: better use `viewpager`

Comment: @Paresh i'm not using asynchronous image loading library because it seems that they work mainly with URL loading but in my case, the images comes from local. I do not use a ViewHolder class because the only child view is a ImageView, but i consider when the view==null and when view!=null i set imageBitmap

Comment: @prabhakaran the ViewPager has only one item visible at a time (in some cases i've seen 3 visible items at a time), and the paging goes one-to-one item and i like more as the multi-paging does with the Gallery widget

Comment: @Billyjoker try this https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Comment: @prabhakaran what's the point with that code sample? It contains an example with a ViewPager and a zoomable ImageView...